# Save a new row based on existing activerecord object, setting id to nil didn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to save 2 rows, the 2nd row based on the 1st row:

```
user = User.new(....)
user.save!

user.id = nil
user.name = "different name"
user.save!
```

This doesn't create a 2nd row, what should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that Rails thinks you're trying to change an instance that is already saved to the database, rather than create a new one. What you want to do is clone the original record, and it should work. Here are the [Rails docs on using clone](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveResource/Base.html#method-i-clone).

```
# First instance
user = User.create(...params...)

# New instance (no need to set id = nil)
user2 = user.clone
user2.name = "different name"
user2.save!
```

Comment: Didn't know about clone. Good answer!

Comment: as of rails 4 this is not true anymore. clone will change the initial object, not creating a new instance.

`# First instance
user = User.create(...params...)

# New instance (no need to set id = nil)
user2 = User.new( user.attributes )
user2.name = "different name"
user2.save!`

Comment: or just use `user2 = user.dup`
this will set the id to nil

Comment: This just overwrites the original record for me.  Cristi's suggestion of using user2 = user.dup and then user2.save! created the duplicate record correctly for me.  Using Rails 3.

Answer (score 1):

```
user = User.new( :name => 'whatever')
user.save!

user = User.new( :name => 'other name')  
user.save!
```

or even better, just do:

```
User.create( :name => 'first user name' )
User.create( :name => 'second user name' )
```

...for as many users as you need.

If you want to repeat the conditions for all of these except the name, you could just save your repeated params to an instance variable and set the non-repeating attributes on each create. Something like:

```
attributes = { :gender => :male, :age => 18 }
User.create( :name=> 'John', attributes }
User.create( :name=> 'Fred', attributes }
```